# Whether I should post a same question to other similar StackExchange communities or not?

Tags: discussion

I have a question about my Unix & Linux Stack Exchange post: [Why install lxde-core no include the lxterminal recommend?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/363357/why-install-lxde-core-no-include-the-lxterminal-recommend)

Whether I should post a same question to other similar StackExchange communities or not?
Particularly,I should done this when my question no any useful answer?

Comment: By the way, I just mentioned your question to one of our local Debian experts and I edited it to try and make it clearer (that might also be a reason why you didn't get many reactions). So I suggest you wait a little while, there may be an answer coming now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, please don't post the same question on multiple Stack Exchange sites. That is [explicitly against the rules](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu). If you want to ask on another site, you can either:

1. Delete the post here and repost it on the other site.
2. Flag it for moderator attention and ask us to migrate it for you.

But don't post the same question on multiple sites, that can end up with all copies of the question closed. Finally, I can't imagine any other site more suited for your question. It would also be on topic on Super User but it is a better fit here. Still, moving it is absolutely your choice.